# Writing an object-oriented MySQLdb connection

Tags: python

I am trying to learn OOP, and I am using the database connection via `MySQLdb` as my first test. This is what I have so far:

```
class DBConnection:
    def __init__(self, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME):
        self.host = DB_HOST
        self.port = DB_PORT
        self.name = DB_NAME
        self.user = DB_USER
        self.password = DB_PASSWORD

    def get_conn(self):
        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = self.DB_HOST, port = self.DB_PORT,
                                db = DB_NAME, user = DB_USER,
                                passwd = DB_PASSWORD)
        return conn

    def get_cursor(self):
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        return cursor

    def get_dict_cursor(self):
        dict_cursor = self.conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        return dict_cursor
```

Is the above valid? Does `self.conn` refer to `get_conn()` or is this an invalid reference. How would I establish a connection to the database and then get a cursor, using the python shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't defined `self.conn` anywhere.  You're only setting `conn` as a local inside of `get_conn`.  Define `self.conn` in your constructor, and then update `get_conn` to set `self.conn`.  Like this:

```
class DBConnection:
    def __init__(self, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME):
        self.host = DB_HOST
        self.port = DB_PORT
        self.name = DB_NAME
        self.user = DB_USER
        self.password = DB_PASSWORD
        self.conn = None

    def get_conn(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = self.host,
                                    port = self.port,
                                    db = self.name,
                                    user = self.user,
                                    passwd = self.password)
```

Also, check whether `self.conn` is set first as opposed to creating a new one each time in `get_conn`, like this:

```
def get_conn(self):
    if self.conn is None:
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = self.host,
                                    port = self.port,
                                    db = self.name,
                                    user = self.user,
                                    passwd = self.password)
    return self.conn
```

Finally, call the `get_conn` method like this:

```
mydbconnobj = DBConnection('localhost',3306,'foouser','foopass','foodbname')
mydbconn = mydbconnobj.get_conn()
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "consider using a static (class) method to get self.conn as opposed to creating a new one each time in get_conn." ?

Comment: Why are you using `self.DB_HOST` and `self.DB_PORT`, but not `self` with `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, and `DB_PASSWORD`?

Comment: I copied this from your code...I'll clean up the errors.  Stand by.

Comment: Ok thanks. (I would clean up my errors, but I'm not sure what is correct and what isn't from what I currently have)